# Next Auth returning email as undefined from session

Tags: next.js, next-auth, next.js13

To utilize the latest UI enhancements from Next Auth, I needed to upgrade to Next.js v13. After upgrading to Next.js v13 from 12.0.10, I noticed I cannot create a new post. It appears the email is not returning from the session after looking at the error. Do note, sign-in does work and retains the session.

**Error**

Invalid `prisma.post.create()` invocation:

```
{
  data: {
    title: "Test",
    content: "test content",
    author: {
      connect: {
        email: undefined,
?       id?: String
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**scheme.prisma**

```
model Post {
  id        String  @id @default(cuid())
  title     String
  content   String?
  published Boolean @default(false)
  author    User?   @relation(fields: [authorId], references: [id])
  authorId  String?
}

model Session {
  id           String   @id @default(cuid())
  sessionToken String   @unique @map("session_token")
  userId       String   @map("user_id")
  expires      DateTime
  user         User     @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@map("sessions")
}

model User {
  id            String    @id @default(cuid())
  name          String?
  email         String?   @unique
  emailVerified DateTime? @map("email_verified")
  image         String?
  createdAt     DateTime  @default(now()) @map(name: "created_at")
  updatedAt     DateTime  @updatedAt @map(name: "updated_at")
  posts         Post[]
  accounts      Account[]
  sessions      Session[]

  @@map(name: "users")
}
```

**pages/api/post/index.ts**

```
import { getSession } from "next-auth/react";
import prisma from "../../../lib/prisma";

export default async function handle(req, res) {
  const { title, content } = req.body;

  const session = await getSession({ req });
  const result = await prisma.post.create({
    data: {
      title: title,
      content: content,
      author: { connect: { email: session?.user?.email } },
    },
  });
  res.json(result);
}
```